# ActiveMQ prebvents new subscribers from getting frames, once there are frames

Tags: php, python, queue, activemq-classic, stomp

I have tried this with several libs and languages (php5|php7|Stomp extension|ZF1 Stomp| Python2.7 Stomp package).
What I found out is that if there is a subscriber to a queue, and it start to get messages (frames) from the queue, any new subscriber during that time will not be getting any of the messages.

My question:
Is there a way to create a new subscriber to a queue that currenty have messages in it + an existing subscriber, and that the new subscriber will receive those messages.
I do not send the Exclusive subscriber headers.
If I had two subscriber prior to getting the messages, both will participate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely running into issues with prefetching where the first client has prefetched all the messages and is churning through them while the second gets none as a result.  To tackle this you should configure the clients with a small prefetch value such as 1 using the values given in the [ActiveMQ STOMP guide](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html).  The client needs to add header activemq.prefetchSize:1 or the like.

You could also set the client subscription to use client acknowledgement mode which will allow you to control when the message is considered handled and prevent the broker from dispatching more messages.

Comment: I am Acknowledging each message after I finish processing it successfully. IF I have two subscribers prior to sending the messages, the subscribers each gets (almost) an equal share of the messages. Does that make sense with the prefetching scenario? (Maybe AMQ sees how many subscribers and sends them equal parts?)

Comment: Depends on how many message there are when they subscribe, the first guy in gets a batch of messages sent to him, the next guy in might not see any if the first one took them all.  There are many gotchas when trying to do sharing and prefetch balance is one of them.

Comment: so, just to verify, there is no such "block" on new subscribers once there are existing messages in the queue. I will try the prefetch 1. btw, is it just me or most people do not even use queues?

Comment: It'd be impossible to say what exactly is happening without seeing the application code and testing the use case.  STOMP can be a bit more tricky to get right due to the simplistic nature of the protocol.